# One preselected shipping method by chosen payment method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method, payment-method

With the code bellow, the customer needs to select a shipping method in order to update and change the payment methods (COD will hide the other payment methods):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'my_custom_available_payment_gateways');
function my_custom_available_payment_gateways($gateways) {
    $shipping_method ='flat_rate:8'; //2-7
    $shipping_method2 ='flat_rate:9';
    global $woocommerce;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method || $chosen_shipping == $shipping_method2) {
        unset( $gateways['easypay_mb'] );
        unset( $gateways['easypay_mbway'] );
        unset( $gateways['easypay_cc'] );
        unset( $gateways['paypal'] );
        unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
    }
    return $gateways;
}
```

BUT I need something different and I'm not finding anything related to that.

I would like that each available payment method will enable one pre-defined shipping method at the time, without allowing customer to change of shipping method *(so without displaying shipping method radio buttons options choice)*.

Is it possible? Can someone point me to the right direction?